# Putting up posters in hard to reach places

Tags: walls, painting, stairs, ladder

I'd like to place posters in a hard to reach spot in my home.

The posters are pretty sturdy. They're glossy prints on thick cardstock paper.

I'd like to place them up along a tall wall, except that the wall is directly above the staircase.

I can't use the ladder because the staircase is there, and there's no way I could reach high enough on my own.

Are there poles or other equipment that might be helpful for putting up posters in hard to reach places?

Edit- I found these two possible solutions. [Ladder Ledge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07LGVQTPM) and [Staircase platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MZDLVC3). I like the idea of placing my ladder directly on the stores, but I'd rather not spend $150 for this solution

Comment: do image search for `ladder on stair`

Answer (score -1):

If you're only going to ever need it for your own staircase investing in such an expensive adjustable platform may not be warranted.

you can probably build your own from some some 6x2 lumber

cut pieces to make the basic shape of the ladder ledge and fasten the parts together with structural screws, fit rubber feet or a layer of rubber anti-slip floor surface 
to the underside,

Comment: If you don't want or need to purchase then **hire** the proper gear and **stay** safe. mickey mouse constructions can (and do) lead to accidents.